# iOS: Could not get outgoing call events in CallKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, callkit

I'm making a call through my app using 'telprompt', but when call ends I want a new view controller to be shown and hit an API to get data, So I want to receive an event to open a pop up and hit API.

I have tried using CallKit, but Delegate method is not getting called.

here is my code.

```
#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>
#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>
```

I have conform to CXCallObserverDelegate

In viewDidLoad:

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
[callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

Delegate method:

```
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call connected **********/n");

    } else if(call.hasEnded) {

        NSLog(@"********** voice call disconnected **********/n");

    }
}
```

Above method is not getting called, As you can see I have already set delegate, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing a strong reference to the callObserver object after creating a strong reference/property to my controller it works well.

Add the property and put callObserver object in it.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallObserver *callObserver;
```

viewDidLoad:

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
[callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
_callObserver = callObserver;
```

Now Delegate method will be called.

Cheers !!!