# iOS CallKit CXCallObserver delegate method callChanged never fires

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I’ve read several other posts, such as this one: [iOS: Could not get outgoing call events in CallKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915871/ios-could-not-get-outgoing-call-events-in-callkit).  The solution is invariably to make sure the reference to the CXCallObserver object is strong so that it won’t disappear before it is needed.  I believe I have done that and still have the problem.  I’m using Objective-C, SDK 11.3; the code builds fine, no errors or crashes occur.  The callChanged method just never fires.  Any ideas?

Here’s my code:

CXCallObserverDelegate.h:  (Not sure why I needed to create this myself, but my code won’t build without it.  However, when I do, I get a warning that the “Duplicate definition is ignored.”  Doesn't seem like this should be a problem, but could it be?).

```
#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>
#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>

@protocol CXCallObserverDelegate

    - (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver
        callChanged:(CXCall *)call;

@end
```

MyViewController.h:

```
#import "CXCallObserverDelegate.h"

@interface MyViewController: MixpanelTrack <OtherDelegate,AnotherDelegate,CXCallObserverDelegate>
```

{ … }

MyViewController.m:

```
#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>
#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>

@property (atomic, strong) CXCallObserver *callObserver;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self launchCallObserver];

}


-(void) launchCallObserver {

    CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.callObserver = callObserver;    

}


-(void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@“I never see this“ type:TSMessageNotificationTypeSuccess];

    } else if (call.hasEnded) {
        [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@“I never see this either“ type:TSMessageNotificationTypeSuccess];        
    }
}
```

I’m making calls programmatically through my app with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
```

Comment: Try to make AppDelegate as `CXCallObserver`. AppDelegate correct handles all calls events.

Answer (score 0):

I checked our project and I saw your issue: You are using imports classes instead Callkit framework, so you are overriding `CXCallObserverDelegate` when you never import this protocol.

To solve this issue you need import framework with:

```
#import <CallKit/CallKit.h>
```

instead

```
#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>
#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your response, Antonio.  Unfortunately, I'm still not getting any callChanged action.  I changed all my import statements to only reference <CallKit/CallKit.h>.  I also was able to remove my custom CXCallObserverDelegate.h file with no ill effects.  Don't know what was up with that.  I've also tried moving the whole thing to the AppDelegate class, setting up the CXCallObserver object from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Anything I try builds fine, runs fine, just doesn't do anything on callChanged.

Comment: Hi @TomPeterson , are you sure that MyViewController is instantiated when callChanged is called? We have a manager for it (configured when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is called). Other question... Are you emulating or using app calls or are you using other calls (like GSM, Whatsapp, etc)?

Comment: I’m pretty sure the MyViewController is instantiated and stays that way when the call is started and ended.  The MyViewController view displays image icons of potential call recipients.  When the user clicks on one, they are prompted by a dialog to call that recipient, with the main screen opaque behind.  When the user clicks an icon to initiate a call, a splash screen is added as a subview to the window for just a second, then the phone’s native calling view and apparatus takes over for the duration of the call.

Comment: When the call terminates, the splash screen reappears for another second, then the MyViewController view reappears in the same state in which it had been left, (i.e., if the user had scrolled to find the desired call recipient, the page returns at that same spot in the scrolling.  So it seems the view has not been reloaded).

Comment: I also know that in this process, when the user clicks to call, the AppDelegate.applicationWillResignActive() method fires, but just one second later applicationDidBecomeActive() fires.  So the app seems to have been in the inactive state for just a second, no matter how long the call is.  I had originally tried to measure a call’s duration with these two methods, but that didn’t work for this reason.

Comment: My calls are being placed by the UIApplication.openUrl() method.  There are no intermediate calling apps being used.
Can you explain how the Manager works?  Maybe that’s what I need.

Comment: Hi, I was checking our project and we found two differences: First we use CXCallController instead CXCallObserver. And we don't use openURL() method because our calls are in app, like Whatsapp call, it isn't GSM call. In few hours i will check better our project and i hope to help you, so we have a providerDelegate. Meanwhile you can test CXCallController.

Comment: I tried using CXCallController to create the CXCallObserver object, with no luck. Then I tried starting the call with CXCallController.requestTransactionWithAction.  That started the call successfully, but still nothing registered in the CXCallObserver's callChanged method.  Is there some way you're getting around using the CXCallObserver altogether?

Comment: I was reviewing our project and I saw that our application when it is in background does not use the function callObserver:callChanged :, but when we use requestTransaction:completion: it works without problems. I'm sorry I can not help you anymore, because we have it like you approximately

Comment: Thank you for your time, Antonio.